# Dynamically List contents of a table in database that continously updates

Tags: oracle, monitoring

It's kinda real-world problem and I believe the solution exists but couldn't find one.

So We, have a Database called **`Transactions`** that contains tables such as `Positions`, `Securities`, `Bogies`, `Accounts`, `Commodities` and so on being updated continuously every second whenever a new transaction happens. For the time being, We have replicated master database Transaction to a new database with name TRN on which we do all the querying and updating stuff.

We want a sort of monitoring system (  like [htop process viewer in Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28WvO.gif)) for Database that dynamically lists updated rows in tables of the database at any time.

**`TL;DR`** Is there any way to get a continuous updating list of rows in any table in the database?

Currently we are working on Sybase & Oracle DBMS on Linux (Ubuntu) platform but we would like to receive generic answers that concern most of the platform as well as DBMS's(including MySQL) and any tools, utilities or scripts that can do so that It can help us in future to easily migrate to other platforms and or DBMS as well.

Comment: For Oracle you may be able to do this with [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm#BDCGGACA).  But this is an advanced topic, the chances of a generic solution existing between multiple databases is low.  Or possibly you could use a system like Oracle Goldengate, that works with different database transaction logs, but is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

To list updated rows, you conceptually need either of the two things:

1. The updating statement's effect on the table.
2. A previous version of the table to compare with.

How you get them and in what form is completely up to you.

The 1st option allows you to list updates with statement granularity while the 2nd is more suitable for time-based granularity.

Some options from the top of my head:

- Write to a temporary table
- Add a field with transaction id/timestamp
- Make clones of the table regularly

AFAICS, Oracle doesn't have built-in facilities to get the affected rows, only their count.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of details in the question so not sure how much of this will be of use ...

- 'Sybase' is mentioned but nothing is said about which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)
- by 'replicated master database transaction' I'm assuming this means the primary database is being replicated (as opposed to the database called 'master' in a Sybase ASE instance)
- no mention is made of what products/tools are being used to 'replicate' the transactions to the 'new database' named 'TRN'

So, **assuming** part of your environment includes Sybase(SAP) ASE ...

- MDA tables can be used to capture counters of DML operations (eg, insert/update/delete) over a given time period
- MDA tables can capture some SQL text, though the volume/quality could be in doubt if a) MDA is not configured properly and/or b) the DML operations are wrapped up in prepared statements, stored procs and triggers
- auditing could be enabled to capture some commands but again, volume/quality could be in doubt based on how the DML commands are executed
- also keep in mind that there's a performance hit for using MDA tables and/or auditing, with the level of performance degradation based on individual config settings and the volume of DML activity

**Assuming** you're using the Sybase(SAP) Replication Server product, those replicated transactions sent through repserver likely have all the info you need to know which tables/rows are being affected; so you have a couple options:

- route a copy of the transactions to another database where you can capture the transactions in whatever format you need [you'll need to design the database and/or any customized repserver function strings]
- consider using the Sybase(SAP) Real Time Data Streaming product (yeah, additional li$ence is required) which is specifically designed for scenarios like yours, ie, pull transactions off the repserver queues and format for use in downstream systems (eg, tibco/mqs, custom apps)

I'm not aware of any 'generic' products that work, out of the box, as per your (limited) requirements.  You're likely looking at some different solutions and/or customized code to cover your particular situation.